# Router VPN for mobile remote UPNP & SAMBA

Tags: vpn, router, openvpn, iphone, buffalo

I found those related posts helpful:

[How to setup VPN on home network](https://serverfault.com/questions/21251/how-to-setup-vpn-on-home-network)

https://serverfault.com/questions/38106/vpn-router-recommendations

[Wireless router with vpn server](https://serverfault.com/questions/79472/wireless-router-with-vpn-server)

but I'd like to know how to configure my router and the other necessary components.

I have a Buffalo nfinity router with built-in PPTP VPN Server and OpenVPN support. However, I'd prefer not using OpenVPN because my iPhone and Tablet do not support OpenVPN (I think).
I'd also like not to have to use a computer for the VPN because I will be connecting to multiple computers on the network, not all up all the time. Plus I use my router's USB for mini-NAS sorta setup.

My question is how to configure this VPN setup, specifically so it can be accessed by an iPhone and a Tablet.

Additionaly I will need to set up with a static IP service, any advice on which one? DynDNS isn't free but I'm debating whether to use it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dnsexit.com from free dyndns service, but few routers support these services natively. if you can take up a dyndns account nothing like it.

if you have a static ip, no need for dynamic dns. this is usually provided by your ISP.

PPTP VPN has two steps. 
step 1: configure ip range which would be usually outside your DHCP range, but within the same subnet eg: 192.168.1.0/24 subnet and dhcp is from .63 to .253 . so your PPTP for say 10 devices would be from .50 to .60 .

Step 2: configure users and passwords.

thats it, so now your iPhone or tablet should on a 3G connection, not your internal WiFi, be able to connect to your router, after you give your static IP/DynDns name and your user/pass combo.

in case if you still have issues, make sure the router has port 1723 open for PPTP connections.

you can verify with canyouseeme.org

Comment: Thanks alot for this explanation, but using canyouseeme.org I can't reach port 1723.          I do have PPTP Passthrough enabled in my router, and have configured my router for PPTP VPN (I started the DynDNS 30 day trial and acquired a domain and all...).                                 I contacted my service provider (Clear) and they told me their modems are open for VPN... what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The final answer was to call up my ISP (Clear) and open up port 1723 (: